# How to use same port for two publishers for sending data to the same subscriber using ZeroMQ?

Tags: c++, sockets, zeromq

I am making an application in C++ where two publishers, say `pub1` and `pub2`, are supposed to send data to 3 subscribers, say `s1`, `s2`, `s3`.

The pattern is as following:

`Pub1` sends data to `s1` and `s2`

`Pub2` sends data to `s2` and `s3`

Now, if I am using the different TCP ports for the publishers, it is working, but I need to do it using a single port, when using the same port for both the publishers then only the publisher that is binding first works and the other publisher throws memory error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `zmq::proxy` internally to allow multiple publishing sockets to serve data over one TCP port.

```
P1(subject P1) -inproc-> |                       |--tcp-> SUB(P1)
                         |--XSUB(zmq::proxy)XPUB-|--tcp-> SUB(P1,P2)
P2(subject P2) -inproc-> |                       |--tcp-> SUB(P2)
```

Method:

**Publisher Application**

- Two `PUB` sockets (**inside the publisher app**), one publishes with subject "P1", the other "P2"
- They both connect inside your application to the `XSUB` side of your `zmq::proxy` over `//:inproc`. The proxy is also running inside your publisher application
- Other side of the proxy (`XPUB` side) binds to the single TCP port.

**Subscriber Applications**

- Your subscriber applications connect to the TCP port and subscribe to what they require.

  - For instance S1 will subscribe to "P1" while S2 will subscribe to both "P1" and "P2"
  - e.g `subscribe_sock.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "P1", 2)`
  - e.g `subscribe_sock.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "P2", 2)`